# Where is the use of continuity in this Munkres Topology question?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> 13. Let $A \subset X$; let $f : A \rightarrow Y$ be continuous; let $Y$ be Hausdorff. Show that if $f$ may be extended to a continuous function $g : \bar A \rightarrow Y$, then $g$ is uniquely determined by $f$.

I believe I've solved this, here's an outline:

I assume that for $x \in \overline{A} - A$ we have $g(x) \neq h(x)$ for $g,h$ extensions of $f$ as assumed.

Using the Hausdorff assumption I take two disjoint environments $V_g, V_h \subset Y$.

We have that $x \in g^{-1}(V_g) \cap h^{-1}(V_h) := U$ so $U$ is an environment of $x$ in $X$.

By assumption $\exists z \in A \cap U$ which implies that $f(z) = h(z) = g(z)$ in contradiction to $V_g, V_h$ being disjoint.

Where did I use the continuity of $f$, or is this proof wrong?

Comment: You are using continuity in the sense that if $V_g, V_h$ are open, then $U$ is open. If you do not assume this, then you cannot use the property of closure that $\exists z\in A\cap U$ which implies that...

Comment: I think the word you want in English is "neighborhood," not "environment."

Comment: In English , a neighborhood (nbhd) of a point $p$ is a set $U$  with $p\in V\subset U$ for some open $V.$

Comment: Theorem: If $Y$ is Hausdorff and $f:S\to Y$ and $h:S\to Y$ are continuous then $\{x\in S: f(x)\ne h(x)\}$ is open in $ S$. and therefore  $\{x\in S: f(x)=h(x)\}$ is closed in $S$....... So  in your Q let $S=\bar A.$ If $\bar f:\bar A\to Y$ and $\bar h:\bar A:\to Y$ are continuous and agree on $A$ then  $\{x\in \bar A: \bar f(x)=$ $\bar g(x)\}\supset Cl_{\bar A}A=$ $\bar A.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're taking in $U$ the intersection of two inverse images of open sets under $g$ and $h$. The latter are open by continuity of $g$ resp. $h$ (the intersection is open by the topology axioms). The openness is needed for it to intersect $A$.

The continuity of $f$ is needed because if $f$ has a continuous extension $g$ to $\overline{A}$,  then $g|A$ is also continuous by a standard result in subspaces, and this is by definition $f$ again.

We don't say that $f$ *has* a continuous extension (it need not have: extend $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ to all of the reals..), but if there is one, there can be only one and not more.

Comment: Aha ok! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using continuity of $f$ explicitly. However, you do use continuity of $g$ and $h$ when you construct $U$, and if $f$ is not continuous, then neither are $g$ and $h$.

Comment: So you're saying that I cannot extend a non continuous function with domain $A$ to a continuous function with domain $\overline{A}$?

Comment: If $A$ is already closed, then that is clearly the case, yes.

Comment: @Mariah Yes, that's what I'm saying.